# Android Notepad exercise. Menu isn't working

Tags: java, android

I'm using http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html as a guide.

I've got to step 13 and ran the application, but when I pressed the menu button, the application stopped working:

[image: The problem]

When debugging:

[image: Debugging]

What can I do?

**Edit**
Stacktrace:
[image]
Errors:
[image]

**MoreEdits:**
[image]

Comment: Did you check your code against the one provided in the `Notepadv1Solution`zip file?

Comment: Show us the exception stacktrace from LogCat

Comment: Yes, same code except different spacing. I'll check if the solution will work without exceptions

Comment: Look at the 2nd screenshot - right bottom corner. When you get the exception, the stacktrace is displayed there (click E button in circle for convinience to display only error-level messages)

Comment: It looks like this errors are not produced by your application. Clear the log entries (the very right button "Clear Log"), run you application again and do the steps to get an exception. Only after that see LogCat information.

Comment: Reuploaded more updated screen-shots

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the new proper virtual device and run you app on it